# Netlogo: Iterating over a set of turtles within patch iteration

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to assign each patch a particular value, which is based on its proximity to each of a certain group of turtles. Those values were going to be stored in a table. Is there any way to iterate over turtles within a patch iteration? This is part of my code:

```
ask patches [
    let this_xcor pxcor
    let this_ycor pycor
    if pcolor != obstacle-color [
        ask turtles with [patch-ahead Movement_Speed = obstacle-color][ 
            set patchdist sqrt(((xcor - this_xcor)*(xcor - this_xcor) + (ycor - this_ycor)*(ycor - this_ycor)))
```

Comment: And what's the problem with that code? Does it fail? Where does it fail? Give us more details so we can help you !